# How to manually expire a passsword MariaDB 10.4.17

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I'm trying to expire a users password and although the following command runs successfully it doesn't actually expire the password what am I missing here?

```
ALTER USER 'User'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE
```

Comment: That would seem to be the way to do it so the obvious follow up is *on what basis* have you come to the conclusion that it hasn't worked?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The password expired field in the user table still has a N in it

Comment: is still user can run any query? because when you expire the password, the user still can login but can't do anything else until chose a new passwrd

Comment: also you might have a global configuration on your mysql config file that set the password expiration policy , you might wanna check that

Comment: @eshirvana I checked and it is actually expiring the password but the field still has a N in it lol so I guess my next question is "Why after expiring a MySQL password does the password_expired field still have a N in it?"

Comment: not sure! are you looking at the right user?

Comment: @eshirvana yes definitely